# access href value inside a div tag in c#

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I have some  divs like this:

```
<div class="compTitle options-toggle">
    <h3 class="title">
        <a class=" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24" href="http://www.bestbuy.com/">
            Products - Best Buy
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the href values inside the "compTitle options-togglet" div.how should I get "http://www.bestbuy.com/"?

i use this code for getting title

```
string titles = node.SelectSingleNode(".//h3[contains(@class,'title')]").InnerText;
```

Comment: Hello! Try to use HAPXPathFinder utility to find needed path.

Comment: Try something like `string titles = node.SelectSingleNode(".//h3[@class='title']/a/@href").Value;` or `string titles = node.SelectSingleNode(".//h3[@class='title']/a").Attributes["href"].Value;`

Comment: @Andersson both of them returns error: